# is ID of html controls which called by javascript casesensitive or not

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, dhtml

i have this control

```
 <input id="btnBackMP" type="button" value="<" onclick="BackGroup('MP') ;" 
  disabled="disabled" style="background-color: #BF0000; width: 28px;" />
```

inside backGroup Function i used this Code Line :

```
  document.getElementById('btnback' + Key).disabled = true;
```

this line works fine on Web Dev but when i published my site on server (iis 7)
this line stop working  till i changed it to the following  :

```
document.getElementById('btnBackMP'+ Key).disabled = true;
```

any one have idea ?

thanks

Comment: Regardless of case sensitivity, the two examples you posted aren't even the same value! 'btnback' != 'btnBackMP' (case-sensitive or not). You need to provide more information on the functions being called since clearly case sensitivity is not the issue here.

Comment: Is `key` the value passed into the function? If so, it would seem that it's blank when being passed to the function in the published version.

Comment: the one other thing I feel is imperative to add is that no matter what programming language you use, please maintain case-consistency. if its really that much of a bother, just only use lower-case letters.

Comment: Key is paramter send the right Value  MP this same between local published

Answer (score 2):

Have you changed in calling function argument too since before your are passing 'MP' as argument and using as key

```
<input id="btnBackMP" type="button" value="<" onclick="BackGroup() ;" 
  disabled="disabled" style="background-color: #BF0000; width: 28px;" />
```

and why do not you directly change to this line only :-

```
document.getElementById('btnBackMP').disabled = true;
```

Comment: actually i have many buttons start with part btnBack then concatenate with value of Key parameter which be NV , MP ..etc  . i use this way because one function (backGroup) will handle the activity of all these functions i'am the value of key before calling the line is MP other evidence  when i made the letters to same case everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Element id is case sensitive. The id must be unique but in theory you could use id="elementa" and id="elementA" in the same document to refer on two different nodes.

This is not recommended

Further details on 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.id

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute values are case-sensitive by HTML specifications; see e.g. [HTML 4.01 on `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-id). They are thus case-sensitive when used in JavaScript too. Note that the `document.getElementById` method queries the DOM, which must follow HTML conventions here.

So `btnbackMP` and `btnBackMP` are distinct `id` values. Your code seems to have another error too, as pointed out, but this might be just an issue in formulating the question. (I suppose the last code line was meant to have `btnBack` not `btnBackMP`.)

Comment: good we agree id case sensitive but the problem is my code works fine on my local but when i published the code on server the problem start to appear  why the behaviour changed

Comment: @alaayacoub, apparently the Web Dev you are using has a bug (it fails to apply case-sensitivity rules).

Comment: it's works also on my local IIS anyway i will change id's to small letters and that set thanks