# Case insensitive asp control IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP form in to which I am dynamically inputting controls from database.
Now sometimes I have controls that have the same names if case insensitive.
For example I have one control called:
IDa^0
and another one called 
IDA^0
So it calls an exception even though the to ids are different.
Heres a page with an example.
http://clicke.co.il/AutoForm.aspx?f=%u05d4%u05e6%u05e2%u05d4+%u05dc%u05d1%u05d9%u05d8%u05d5%u05d7+%u05d1%u05e8%u05d9%u05d0%u05d5%u05ea+%u05d0%u05d5+%u05e1%u05d9%u05e2%u05d5%u05d3+2013.pdf

This error occurs on any postback

Multiple controls with the same ID 'IDa^0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Heres a code segment showing how I create the controls:

```
                        TextBox TheItemT = new TextBox();
                        TheItemT.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute");
                        TheItemT.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "transparent");
                        TheItemT.Width = (int)PositionsOfItem[2];
                        TheItemT.Height = (int)PositionsOfItem[3];
                        TheItemT.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, ((int)PositionsOfItem[0]).ToString() + "px");
                        TheItemT.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, ((int)PositionsOfItem[1]).ToString() + "px");
                        TheItemT.ID = ItemID + "^" + AppearanceOfItem;
                        TheItemT.Text = ValuesofItem[0];
                        PanelPages[PageOfItem].Controls.Add(TheItemT);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285669/is-id-of-html-controls-which-called-by-javascript-casesensitive-or-not.                      What error are you getting? Are you trying to access the control from javascript?

Comment: " Multiple controls with the same ID 'IDa^0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs. ". I get this error on any postback.

Comment: While creating control dynamically make sure the ids are unique you can append the control id with some increment-or while creating them . Can you post your code that creates these controls?

Comment: I have to reuse the controls later on so I cant have them being random names. I'd also add something that represents that its a lower case of an existing control but I have no idea what to add or how. It just doesn't make sense to me since ASP should be case sensetive and ignore this kind of thing.

Comment: Don't have controls whose names are the same. Simples. Case sensitivity is harmful. However if you don't like that answer, you can just hex-encode the characters of the name, and use that instead of the name.

Comment: While setting the IDs TheItemT.ID = ItemID + "^" + AppearanceOfItem;    Firstly make it caps by toUpper(). And before adding the control to PanelPages[PageOfItem].Controls.Add(TheItemT); check if already exists. If yes then you got to change the ID with appending some unique stuff to the ID.

Comment: I cant choose the controls IDs I have. I am handling huge amounts of data with IDs that were pre-made in PDF forms. Maximum I can do is encode the chars to ascii per say and use that as ID, but I'd rather just fix this! (Ben, I wrote this before you edited your post.)

Comment: Or one more way to create the unique id is check in the DB table the composite key i.e the unique combination of the fields and use those fields while creating the id, in that way your control id would always be unique.

Comment: Maximum I can do is encode the chars to ascii per say and use that as ID, but I'd rather just fix this! Yup this will work.

Comment: Well thanks guys I did this and I'll work on it. Still rather curious more than anything why does this happen in the first place